# PropertyInfo for a DataRow from its PropertyDescriptor

Tags: c#, datatable, propertyinfo, propertydescriptor

How to get the PropertyInfo for a DataRow from its PropertyDescriptor.

```
//pd is a PropertyDescriptor
var propertyinfo = pd.ComponentType.GetProperty(pd.Name);
```

the above code works fine for a list collection, but it not works while am working with DataTable.

Any idea on this?

Comment: What are you later using `propertyInfo` for? I'm guessing to get the value of the property, but anything else?

Comment: With that i need to get the CustomAttributes..

Comment: Okay, what does `pd.ComponentType` give you when working with a `DataTable`?

Comment: it returns null for DataTable.. ComponentType is typeof DataRowView..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PropertyInfo` is the reflection world, where types have explicit CLI properties. `DataTable` *does not belong to that world*; it uses the `System.ComponentModel` flexible property model, via `TypeDescriptor`, `PropertyDescriptor`, etc. Basically: there **is no property** in the CLI sense. `PropertyDescriptor` can be used (and is used) to describe "properties" in a more flexible, dynamic sense, where the layout is not specified as a type, but is custom-defined, often on-the-fly at runtime.

So no: you can't do this. The question does not make sense; or at least, in the general case it doesn't. There is also "typed datasets", but frankly I strongly recommend staying far far away from them.

Incidentally, you can invent your own pseudo-properties for *any* type - there are extension points for this (`TypeDescriptor`, `ITypedList`, `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, `TypeConverter`, etc); but only code that explicitly uses `System.ComponentModel` will ever see them.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer... i would like to know another thing, how to add validating attributes to a DataColumn..

Comment: @Sankarann define "validating attributes" in this context; which validation framework?

Comment: @Sankarann technically PropertyDescriptor can describe arbitrary attributes - but: it depends on the validation framework choosing to support PropertyDescriptor. So again: what validation framework?

Answer (score 0):

A DataView is built over a DataTable:

> DataView viewData = table.DefaultView;

Since a DataView implements ITypedList, you can get a collection of PropertyDescriptors from it:

> (view as ITypedList).GetItemProperties(null)